# Two sitemap.xml with wordpress in subfolder

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a site at example.com which also hosts a wordpress blog at example.com/blog/

I am generating a sitemap.xml at my main site which also includes urls from my wordpress blog.  What is the proper way to do this?  Should I let wordpress generate its own sitemap.xml under /blog/ and only include urls from my main website in the root sitemap.xml?

Is it hurting anything if they both exist?

Answer (score 5):

A sitemap is so that Google can index your pages without having to scrape and investigate every internal link. If you want something indexed, it should be in there. If you don't want it indexed - robots.txt it.

It doesn't matter if you use multiple sitemaps or a single large file. There's no limits, advantages, disadvantages outside of management.